# Void wordpress CLI script when requiring wp-load.php

Tags: php, wordpress, command-line-interface

I want to import some csv file as posts (custom type) in wordpress multisite instance.
I've to load wordpress functions into my CLI script. So I require wp-load.php file in it.
But after the requiring the script is stopped and nothing happen, no error messages or error code.
Display_errors and logging are on.
Here is the beginning of my script :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define('BASE_PATH', "/srv/www/htdocs/wp/");
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

$blog_id = 26;
require_once(BASE_PATH . 'wp-load.php');
echo $blog_id;
switch_to_blog($blog_id);
```

echo $blog_id did not show up !
I've inserted some echoing in wp-settings.php and wp-config.php and scripts are called.

Any idea ?